# wp_head not injecting css

Tags: functions, css, wp-enqueue-style, frontpage, wp-head

I'm trying to inject a `style.css` script into my `front-page.php`. None of the styles load. In the tutorials, when you inspect page source, all the CSS should be there, but it simply shows the `wp_head()` script without injecting anything. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

### front-page.php

```php
<head>
    <php? 
        wp_head(); 
    ?>
</head>
```

### functions.php

```php
<?php

function load_scripts(){
    echo "Hello Functions!";    
    wp_enqueue_style('any-style-name',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

### folder structure

[image]

### Other scripts I have tried using in `load_scripts`

```php
wp_enqueue_style('any-style-name', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

```php
wp_enqueue_style('anydescription', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), "1.0", 'all');
```

```php
wp_enqueue_style("anydescription", get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), "1.0", "all");
```

Comment: Is your invoking `wp_head()` really precluded by `<php?` or was that a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code block is not properly formated.
You currently have this

```php
<php? 
    wp_head();
?>
```

Notice the opening php tag `<php?`, a correct php tag is `<?php`.
A less than symbol `<` followed by a question mark `?` followed by the word `php`.
So a proper php block would look like this

```php
<?php
    // Your code here
?>
```

There are others you can check out in the official documentation, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: I've been reviewing my code a million times but didn't see an error so simple. Thanks so much! Is there some sort of extension yo use to catch errors like this in the code editor?